# How does my professor go from this exponential equation to a logarithmic one?

Tags: algorithms, proof-writing, recursive-algorithms

[image]

---

How does the "therefore" portion work? How does that exponential equation come to equal n(lgn + 1)?

Comment: Set $n=2^k$ and substitute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first line, $n=2^k$, so from the next to last we substitute in.  Given this definition, $k=\lg n, k2^k=n \lg n$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $k = log_2(n) \Longrightarrow 2^k(k + 1)$

Substitute!